# Cumulative SUM in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, cumulative-sum

I wrote a query in SQLite that cumulates VALUE and it is good if I order by ID only (ID is auto increment int). But, if I want to order by DATE and then by ID, the query shows me wrong results. Any ideas?

Query:

```
select t1.ID, 
       t1.DATE, 
       t1.VALUE, 
       sum(t2.VALUE) as TOTAL     
from test t1
inner join test t2 on t1.DATE >= t2.DATE and t1.id >= t2.id 
group by t1.ID, t1.DATE
order by t1.DATE desc, t1.ID desc
```

Results:

```
ID  DATE        VALUE   TOTAL
9   2015-01-16  55      281 -- should be 226 + 55 = 281
6   2015-01-15  10      26  -- should be 216 + 10 = 226
5   2015-01-15  5       16  -- should be 211 +  5 = 216
8   2015-01-14  100     211
7   2015-01-14  100     111
4   2015-01-13  5       11
3   2015-01-12  3       6
2   2015-01-11  2       3
1   2015-01-10  1       1
```

Comment: Additional problem is when ID goes to 3 chars in lenght or more but the same date.

Comment: How much data are we talking? And is the ordering ad-hoc or predefined?

Comment: Unlimited data, but it will be limited by 50. Ordering is predefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least on the small data, changing the join to something like this:

```
t1.DATE||substr('00000'||t1.id,-5) >= t2.DATE||substr('00000'||t2.id,-5)
```

works fine... So we are building up a "sort key" based on the date and the id (padded with zeros to 5 digits) and using that in the join. It might be necessary to build an index on that to deal with performance though

Comment: I knew it :) ... Thank you.

Comment: @Arnes - it looks like you might need to persist that sort key to a column... that might be enough to speed it up anyway. If not its just as here: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html